# ERROR: Cannot start PyCharm: No JDK found

Tags: pycharm

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 (32-bit).

I downloaded the PyCharm tar file , I went into the bin file from my terminal and then typed

```
./pycharm.sh
```

*but I had the error:*

```
ERROR: Cannot start PyCharm: No JDK found. Please validate either PYCHARM_JDK,JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.
```

How can this be solved ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps:

1. `sudo gedit or sudo xed /usr/share/pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh`
2. find Line: `` JDK=`update-alternatives --list java | grep java-8 | sed 's,jre/bin/java,,' `` and replace it with `JDK = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/' or JDK = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/'` if you're using openjdk.
3. Save and exit
4. Rerun PyCharm

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although the first command in step 1 returns : command not found
and the second command returns : sudo: xed: command not found

Comment: can you try with sudo nano

Comment: OK I typed sudo nano and now i have a window with several options (get help, write out, read file, where is , replace, cut text, justify, go to line,....)